# How do I get POST data from a free text field?

Tags: python, django, post

Doing a modified version of the polls tutorial. Comments work with the database when I go in the python manage.py shell but I can't get it to actually read the post data. Any time I post a comment, the page re-renders but no comment in the database.

Here are my models for an individual Entry and a Comment

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Comment(models.Model):
    entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry)
    comment = models.TextField()
    comment_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

In the Python shell, I'm able to create comments (that show up in the admin) perfectly.

```
>>> from blog.models import Entry, Comment
>>> e = Entry.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> e.comment_set.create(comment="isn't it pretty to think so?", comment_date=timezone.now())
<Comment: isn't it pretty to think so?>
```

In the detail.html view of each blog entry, a user can add a comment.

```
<h1>{{ entry.title }}</h1>
<p>{{ entry.body }}</p>
<p>{{ entry.tags_set.all }}</p>


<form action="{% url 'blog:comment' entry.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<textarea name="comment101" style="width:300px; height: 70px; maxlength="300"; display:none;">
</textarea></br>
<input type="submit" name="comment101" value="Add comment" />
</form>
```

Views for detail and comment:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from blog.models import Entry, Tags, Comment

def detail(request, entry_id):
    entry = get_object_or_404(Entry, pk=entry_id)
    return render(request, 'entries/detail.html', {'entry': entry})

def comment(request, entry_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Entry, pk=entry_id)
    add_comment = request.POST['comment101']
    #get input name comment from POST data
    p.comment_set.create(comment="add_comment", comment_date=timezone.now())
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog:detail', args=(p.id)))
```

I've exhausted all I know. I tried adding name='comment101' every input/form in detail.html and my comment view replicates exactly what I did in the Python shell.

Lastly, if anyone could point me to something to debug code involving POST data (for Mac), that'd be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the correct view is getting called? Why not print out the contents of `request.POST` and see if your values are getting passed to the server. On the client side, you can use Google Chromes built in developer panel to see what is being sent to the server

Comment: I'm not sure how to print what's being posted. Do I write the code in the view or do I retrieve it in the html doc?

Comment: Is your `urls.py` pointing at the correct view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use `request.POST.get` to get post data:

```
add_comment = request.POST.get('comment101',None)
```

Where None is the default value if nothing is passed. Then in the following lines you should check whether add_comment is None or not by a simple if statement:

```
if add_comment is not None:
    #do the work
```

I also recommend you to control the request type with `request.method == 'POST'`.

Then you can create the comment:

```
comment = Comment()
comment.comment = add_comment;
comment.comment_date = timezone.now()
comment.entry = p

comment.save()
```

To debug, I personally use print keyword. If you would like to see all post data you can iterate and print them. When you use print keyword or method (for python 3) you can see the output in from `./manage.py runserver` outputs.

```
for key, value in request.POST.iteritems():
    print key, value
```

Comment: @izkata was correct about checking URLs.py. I wanted to re-render the form so I gave comment the same URL as detail.html, which didn't sit well. However, your comment allowed me to dive deeper into POST knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
c = Comment(comment=add_comment, comment_date=timezone.now(), entry=p)
c.save()
```

That might be of some use.

Also if you want to debug code it is best to place

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

which gives you interactive console wherever you want it.

In case you want to use something better use ipdb (pip install ipdb)

```
import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```